# Updating a lookup column in SharePoint Online list using PoweShell PnP

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have worked on a PowerShell PnP script to update a column in a cloud-based SharePoint list.
I want to update the column “Parent ID” with the content from “FH ID”. My script works fine on a regular column, but “Parent ID” is a lookup-column and therefore, it has three values: LookupID, LookupValue and TypeId (see image). My script updates LookupId, but we need it to update LookupValue.

Can anyone help with a solution?

In the below script we are testing on one “FH ID” = 1020

```
enter code here

Connect-PnPOnline https://skat.sharepoint.com/sites/ICIfo

 function UpdateColumn(){
 $listName = "FH kontakt"

 $list = Get-PnPList $listName

 $items = Get-PnPListItem $listName

  foreach ($item in $items){
  if ($item["FH_x0020_ID"] -eq "1020"){
  Write-Output $item["FH_x0020_ID"]
  Write-Output $item["FH_x0020_Navn"]
  Write-Output $item["Parent_x0020_ID"]
  Write-Output ""
  Set-PnPListItem -List $listName -Identity $item -Values @{"Parent_x0020_ID" = $item["FH_x0020_ID"]}
  }
  }
  }

  UpdateColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the lookup column in SharePoint online, you need to get the ID of the parent lookup item.

You could refer to this article for more:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/03/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-update-lookup-field.html